# Node.js and coffeescript -- testing app with Mocha and Zombie

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, bdd, mocha.js, zombie.js

I am trying to test a node.js webapp I have started working on with
Mocha and Zombie. But there are a few things I still don't understand
and would like some help. Please note that I am using express

Suppose I am testing the user authentication. Obviously there are two
parts:
1 - the user interface
2 - the behavior, involving the controllers and the models
So, I've decided to separate both parts. For the UI, I have decided to
use zombie. The following link contains the UI tests I've written for
the user authentication: https://gist.github.com/7e45d6884ce2d32e933d
Basically, my user authentication form contains a username and
password input fields and a Sign In button. I am interested in four
scenarios: when at least one of the input field is empty and when both
have been provided by the user.
Although the four tests pass right now, I am still not convinced they
are the right tests, or whether it's enough or does the right thing.
What do you guys (BDD experts) think?
thanks
José

Answer (score 6):

1. Since your tests seem to be asynchronous, you should be calling the `done` function given to the callback of the `it` function

   ```
   it 'should do something', (done) ->
     browser.visit 'somepage', {debug: true}, ->
       done()
   ```
2. You might also want to check for the error message your app prints when there is an error authenticating.
3. Besides checking all the fields are given, you should also test a valid authentication, a wrong password, and existing username if your app provides that error message. And if you went as far as only allowing a number of attempted logins every few minutes, test for that too.